# How can we execute WebUI feature file against multiple browsers using parallel runner or distributed testing?

Tags: java, karate

I am able to execute WebUI feature file against single browser (Zalenium) using parallel runner and defined driver in karate-config.js. How can we execute WebUI feature file against multiple browsers (Zalenium) using parallel runner or distributed testing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Scenario Outline` and the [parallel runner](https://github.com/intuit/karate#parallel-execution). Karate will run each row of an `Examples` table in parallel. But you will have to move the driver config into the `Feature`.

Just add a parallel runner to this sample project and try: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/examples/ui-test

```
Scenario Outline: <type>
  * def webUrlBase = karate.properties['web.url.base']
  * configure driver = { type: '#(type)', showDriverLog: true }

  * driver webUrlBase + '/page-01'
  * match text('#placeholder') == 'Before'
  * click('{}Click Me')
  * match text('#placeholder') == 'After'

Examples:
  | type         |
  | chrome       |
  | geckodriver  |
```

There are other ways you can experiment with, here is another pattern when you have a normal `Scenario` in `main.feature` - which you can then call later from a `Scenario Outline` from a separate "special" feature - which is used only when you want to do this kind of parallel-ization of UI tests.

```
Scenario Outline: <config>
  * configure driver = config
  * call read('main.feature')

Examples:
  | config!                  |
  | { type: 'chromedriver' } | 
  | { type: 'geckodriver' }  | 
  | { type: 'safaridriver' } |
```

EDIT - also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62325328/143475

And for other ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61685169/143475

EDIT - it is possible to re-use the same browser instance for all tests and the Karate CI regression test does this, which is worth studying for ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66762430/143475