# Karate - how to run browser (Firefox) in specific resolution

Tags: automated-tests, karate

Using Karate - geckodriver (Firefox) I need to run it in specific browser window size. According to documentation I have tried (JS configuration file):

```
karate.configure('driver', { type: 'geckodriver', executable: 'geckodriver', start: false, port: 4444, addOptions: ['windows-size=320,200'] });
```

or

```
karate.configure('driver', { type: 'geckodriver', executable: 'geckodriver', start: false, port: 4444, addOptions: ['--windows-size=320,200'] });
```

No error raised, but window size is not 320,200.
Probably there will be some small change in configuration needed.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the window size, use [`driver.dimensions`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#driverdimensions) any time after the `driver` has been initialized:

```
  * driver.dimensions = { x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 800 }
```

If needed, you can do `* driver 'about:blank'` before this if you want to start your flow with the browser in a certain size.

If you really mean the display resolution, that is a harder problem. We have a way to do it for the [Chrome Docker container](https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Docker) by exporting [`KARATE_WIDTH` and `KARATE_HEIGHT`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/develop/karate-docker/karate-chrome/entrypoint.sh) environment variables. If we get some [community help](https://github.com/intuit/karate/projects/3#card-26888794) we can do it for FireFox sooner, also based on a Docker container, or you may be able to create one yourself.

Comment: * driver.dimensions works perfectly. Thank you! One additional question - Is it possible to set it somehow in JS configuration file?

Comment: @RadimBukovský you can, indirectly. set a variable: `config.foo = { x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300 }` and then in a feature: `* driver.dimensions = foo`. but note that you can use a re-usable feature to init the driver, which can be called from `karate-config.js` - also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60581024/143475 - and `driver.dimensions = {}` will work in JS also, if the driver is ready