# Change location of drivers

Tags: karate

When using Karate UI, I would like to set all the browser drivers in the same path, is this possible? and is it customizable? e.g. under resources\drivers you would find chromedriver, geckodriver etc

Comment: my bad, wasn't aware. should have done more reading. all voted and accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managing the driver executable is up to you. What I would do is just add that folder to the [System `PATH`](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.html), and then it should just work.

You can read this answer for other ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66762430/143475