# Is it possible to setBinary() in case of chrome in karate

Tags: karate

do we have anything similar to setBinary() for chrome in karate like how we have in selenium?

```
  ''' System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","chromedriver.exe");
   ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
   options.setBinary("blah/blah/chrome.exe");
   WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options)'''
```

Comment: @Luuk - I know how it works with selenium, my question is about how to achieve similar things in karate. so earlier link doesn't answer my question.

Comment: linked q & a has a link to a second answer, make sure you read that also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66762430/143475

Comment: @Peter.. not sure if you understood the question correctly.. I am not looking for any tricks.. do we have something in karate where within the driver config i could provide.

Comment: so my response is if you read the 2 answers and it does not show you a way to do it - please assume that Karate cannot do what you want and look for another tool.