# [karate]: Karate UI Automation: Unable to launch the browser

Tags: karate

The compiler is looking target folder for the chrome.exe file. In which it is looking for some chrome_1639142447236 file. Actually it is available at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application` this location.
Below error message I'm getting:

> 18:51:39.096 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3] ERROR com.intuit.karate -
> org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to
> localhost:9222 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]
> failed: Connection refused: no further information, http call failed
> after 4022 milliseconds for URL: http://localhost:9222 18:51:39.098
> [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3] ERROR com.intuit.karate - http request
> failed:

Below is the feature level error message:

> failed features: src.test.java.examples.users.Sample: Sample.feature:9
>
> - driver config / start failed:  org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to
>   localhost:9222 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]
>   failed: Connection refused: no further information, options:
>   {type=chrome, target=null}

Answer (score 0):

If you know where the `chrome` executable is, please follow the instructions to customize it in your Karate tests: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#configure-driver

```
* configure driver = { type: 'chrome', executable: 'chrome' }
```

Also read this answer for even more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66762430/143475

Comment: tried above solution it worked. I was able to launch the browser. But it was not executing scenario. The browser is just opened for few seconds and closed. Showing below error message.  driver config / start failed: chrome server returned empty list from http://localhost:9222, options: {executable=C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe, target=null, type=chrome} am i missing something here

Comment: no idea. ui automation is not easy, so all the best

Comment: @PeterThomas: Can u please tell me how to Launch Chrome browser in incognito mode
* configure driver = { type: 'chrome', showDriverLog: false, headless: true}
This is just launching the chrome, please help me am searching this solution across forums and not getting it please help

Comment: @DineshTejaj I really don't know. you can read this and contribute your findings back to the community. this needs research: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1935

Comment: @PeterThomas : i got some reference from internet
* configure driver = { type: 'chrome', options: { args: ['--incognito'] } }
Even this is not launching, can u have a look my question is simp;e how to launch a chrome browser in incognito mode? can u help