# How can I integrate the "WebDriverManager" library into Karate for Web Automation?

Tags: java, testing, ui-automation, karate, browser-automation

**WebDriverManager integration with Selenium is as follows;**

```
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

class ChromeCreateTest {

    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        driver = WebDriverManager.chromedriver().create();
    }


    @Test
    void test() {
        // Your test logic here
    }

}

How to integrate Karate with WebDriverManager?
```

I couldn't find a Karate project configured with WebDriverManager from Github.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager

Can I integrate all browsers into karate with WebDriverManager? Thanks for your support

Comment: please read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66762430/143475 - so  the short answer is there is no direct support, but you can easily integrate it if needed. I am not aware of any sample project though