# why Karate tests running on chrome even when i didn't provide chrome path in path variable of my system

Tags: karate

I want to understand how karate is picking up chrome browser on my local machine even though:

1. i didn't maintain chrome path in path variable of my mac system
2. I didn't download chromerdriver.exe neither i put it in my karate project dir

here is the command which is in my `karate-config.js`

```
karate.configure('driver', { type: 'chrome', addOptions: ["--remote-allow-origins=*"] });
```

Also i want to understand why karate is not picking up firefox on my local machine:

```
karate.configure('driver', { type: 'geckodriver', executable: 'geckodriver'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Karate looks for where Chrome is installed by default.

To "pick up" geckodriver, make sure you have the executable in your System PATH, or you can give the absolute path. Please refer to the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#configure-driver

Comment: @PeterSmith i kept geckodriver.exe in my karate project, but i didn't setup in PATH variable. How can i write absolute path, i am confused

Comment: @Yash I can only point you to this answer if it helps, else I give up: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66762430/143475