How to Run Multiple Karate UI Automation Scenarios in the Same Browser Session?
I am working on UI automation with Karate, and I have three scenarios written to perform different actions on the same web application. Currently, for each scenario, the browser is initialized, performs the actions, and then closes. However, I want to run all three scenarios in the same browser session, so the browser doesn't quit and reopen between each scenario.
Here’s an example of what my current scenarios look like:
Feature: Verify Search Text field on Google Home Page

    Background:
      * def baseUrl = 'https://www.google.com/'
      * configure driver = { type: 'chrome', timeout: 5000 }
      * driver baseUrl
      * driver.maximize()
      * waitForUrl(baseUrl)
      * delay(1000)

    Scenario Outline: Enter Search Text <searchText>
      * clear("//textarea[@name='q']")
      * input("//textarea[@name='q']", '<searchText>')
      And delay(5000).screenshot()

      Examples:
        | searchText |
        | Amazon     |
        | Flipkart   |

    Scenario: Verify Privacy Page Link is clickable
      * click("//a[text()='Privacy']")
      And delay(5000).screenshot()

Gone through the Karate Docs and Stackoverflow
https://karatelabs.github.io/karate/karate-core/#clear
But could not find any Solution for the Same.

it is possible if you use a "wrapper" feature and then do a call refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66762430/143475
