# Karate UI testing: how to prevent browser closing at the end of Scenario

Tags: automated-tests, webdriver, karate

I am working on UI automated tests using Karate framework. I am really enjoyng working with this great tool, but it's something that I'm trying to resolve for a while and can't find any solution.

I have a feature file with **3 scenarios** and I want to open the browser and to make login only **once**, before all scenarios, and to be closed only after the last scenario is finished.
In my case driver is started at separated login.feature file which is called from **Background** using 'callonce read('login.feature')' command. I've seen somewhere that if driver is started before scenario. In my case it's not working. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this answer as a reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60581024/143475

So it is supposed to work if you create a feature and then call the other scenarios from that feature.  Karate is designed to close the driver after a `Scenario` by default.

I also recommend that when you have a flow, don't try to split it into different Scenarios. Or you should be prepared to call different features from one Scenario.