# Ability to execute tests on data sets in a csv file 'in parallel'

Tags: multithreading, api, parallel-processing, karate, dataprovider

I asked in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63387913/karate-ability-to-execute-tests-on-a-specific-set-of-data-in-a-csv-file) if Karate is capable of executing tests on specific data sets (For instance, based on priority p0,p1) given in a csv file.

2. Now my second question is if Karate is capable of executing tests on specific data sets in a csv file **in parallel**?

Example: DataProvider supports data-provider-thread-count. Here's an example of [usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31521466/testng-parallel-execution-with-dataprovider).

I've read the [documentation](https://intuit.github.io/karate/#parallel-execution) in regards to parallel execution in Karate, however I did not find anything on this type of parallel feature. Can you please let me know if this is possible in Karate. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes if you use a `Scenario Outline` each row will run in parallel. And this applies to even the "Dynamic" `Scenario Outline` as explained here: https://github.com/intuit/karate#dynamic-scenario-outline

Karate runs each `Scenario` in parallel and behind the scenes, each `Examples` row is turned into a `Scenario`. A few paragraphs below it is mentioned in the docs: https://intuit.github.io/karate/#parallel-stats