# Running Karate UI tests with "driverTarget" in GitLab CI

Tags: playframework, sbt, karate

I would like to run Karate UI tests using the `driverTarget` options to test my Java Play app which is running locally during the same job with `sbt run`.

I have a simple assertion to check for a property but whenever the tests runs I keep getting `"description":"TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null`
This is my `karate-config.js`:

```
if (env === 'ci') {
karate.log('using environment:', env);
karate.configure('driverTarget',
    {
        docker: 'justinribeiro/chrome-headless',
        showDriverLog: true
    });
}
```

This is my test scenario:

```
Scenario: test 1: some test
Given driver 'http://localhost:9000'
* waitUntil("document.readyState == 'complete'")
* match attribute('some selector', 'some attribute') == 'something'
```

My guess is that because `justinribeiro/chrome-headless` is running in its own container, `localhost:9000` is different in the container compared to what's running outside of it.

Is there any workaround for this? thanks

Comment: please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66005331/143475