# Running Karate in Github Actions?

Tags: karate, github-actions

I have got Github project for a backend which has an elaborate REST API. I would like to add Karate-based testing as one of the Github Actions steps.

Has anybody written a Github Action that runs standalone Karate to do test against a backend? (Feels like something that more people might want to do.. but I couldn't find anything)

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is because Karate is typically "just another JUnit project" - so if you are for e.g. maven based, you just use an existing Maven GitHub action and you should be good.

FWIW - here is how Karate runs a CI job on GitHub: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66005331/143475