# want to use Karate UI automation on OS not including GUI, am not friendly Java

Tags: ui-automation, github-actions, karate

I want to use Karate UI Automation over Github Actions.

First, I saw the doc:https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/ZIP-Release
Zip release is for the non-programmer, specially non-Java-Programmer, in my guess.
I only use visual studio code on Ubuntu. This Ubuntu only has CLI, not has GUI.

doc:https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/ZIP-Release only mentions Windows and Mac OS.

But, Test Engineer try to use CI/CI tool like Github Actions, even if I use Windows or Mac OS, Github Actions doesn't have GUI, so ZIP-Release is not useful on Ubuntu not including GUI, in my guess.

So, wow should I do to use Karate UI Automation on OS not including GUI.

Comment: the karate UI regression test suite runs on GitHub actions. please read this for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66005331/143475 - and we have docker support. please try and next time ask a more specific question

Comment: thanks, I could use Karate UI automation, using quickstart and UI automation examples.