# How Can I run Karate Api tests via docker and then expose the reports (using docker)?

Tags: docker, api, karate, web-api-testing

I have a docker file:

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-11 as karate

COPY . /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/target/cucumber-html-reports
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
```

Then I run it: docker run --name karate --rm -it imvu_api_mvn mvn test '-Dkarate.options=--tags @feed_comment'

But I can't access the reports because the container exits.

I'd like to know how can I expose the reports after running the tests via docker

Comment: 2 suggestions. learn about how to "mount" volumes in docker. https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/ - and also refer some docs created by the karate team: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66005331/143475