# Multithreading in Dynamic Data Driven Testing

Tags: karate

I have a scenario where I need to run the same test N number of times, each time with slightly different data. The goal here is to capture a rare behavior in the application.

So I come up with the following test codes:

```
Scenario:
  * json testJSONArray = # A JSON Array containing N number of generated test data entries, each of them is a JSON object
  * call read('map.feature@testMultiple') testJSONArray
```

From what I understand, calling a feature and passing in a N-sized JSON array will make the feature run for N number of times.

The question here is, is this run multi-threaded? Because from what I am observing, the run time seems to be longer than expected.

For example, when I run with 10 threads:

- When N = 1, the run time is about 20 seconds.
- When N = 5, the run time is about 90 seconds.
- When N = 10, the run time is about 150 seconds.

So I just want to make sure the scenario here is fulling utilizing multithread feature of Karate.

**Edit:** Adding in the runner

```
Results results = Runner.path(features)
  .tags(tags)
  .parallel(10);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using the parallel runner, ala: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/DemoTestParallel.java ?

Comment: Yes, please refer to my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `call` is never multi-threaded. You have to get proper `Scenario`-s into the picture.

This answer may give you the hint you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60387907/143475

Also refer the documentation: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#dynamic-scenario-outline - and pay attention to the option of using a JS function to generate data. But note that the "Dynamic Scenario Outline" will undergo a [bit of a refactor](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1905).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I modified my code to use javascript generator with Scenario Outline. Now the run time for N = 10 is only ~25 seconds.