# Does Karate support running features in parallel with a karate.call?

Tags: karate

Does Karate support the execution of the called feature in parallel w.r.t data,  when called using karate.call ? Example below -

```
def result = call read(sometest.feature) [{"a":10, "b":20, {{"a":11, "b":20}]
```

Does Karate support the invocation of sometest.feature in parallel for the two datasets in the JSON array?

I tried with a thread count of 2 for the given example and each object in the JSON array is picked up sequentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, once you are in a `call` of any kind, it is all on the same thread that was called from.

So the recommendation is to use a `Scenario Outline`. Karate 1.3.0 makes this easier even for dynamically created data-arrays, please refer the new `@setup` life-cycle: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#setup

For more ideas, refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60387907/143475

Comment: This is wonderful. Thanks for pointing out version 1.3.0. I was trying with 1.2.0 and kept getting "setup" is undefined. Should have read the release notes.