# Karate- JobExecutor unable to read karate-config.js and karate-base.js files

Tags: karate

I am trying to distribute my karate tests using JobExecutor on 2 nodes. Currently I am doing on my local machine and it is starting the job server as well. But it is throwing error like "'url' is undefined" which I have set in karate-config.js file. Looks like it is not reading my karate-config.js file

Also How Can I run tests parallelly on one single node? Observed that test run one by one on node after distributing the tests

I am referring the code from the link https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/master/examples/jobserver/src/test/java/jobtest/simple/SimpleLocalJobRunner.java

Please help. Thank you!!

Comment: to be honest not many teams use this as for API testing parallel threads on a single machine is more than enough. so this is not a priority. that said, it is a great opportunity for you or your team to contribute code. so please proceed keeping that in mind: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#parallel-execution

Comment: Thank you @PeterThomas. Sorry, I missed to mention UI tests here in my question. I am trying this for UI tests.  I will try my best how I can contribute more in this particular issue Thank you

Comment: yes that would be great. for UI tests a lot of teams just use Docker with parallel threads and it may be enough: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60387907/143475