# Nested features seems to get overruled parallel execution behavior

Tags: karate

When trying to run various features in a kind of nested manner, it seems to me that in certain setup it does not respect / execute parallel execution information correct.

Example of features structure and how they are orchestrated

- 1. orchestration-main (This runs the 2 nested features serial

  - 2. orchestration-parallel-setup (This runs the nested feature 3 times in parallel)

    - 3. orchestration-parallel-setup-single (This has only serial scenarios)
  - 4. orchestration-parallel-tests (This runs some scenarios inside in parallel)

Now it looks like if I call 2 and 4 all works fine. However, when I call 1 it looks like as this is defined as serial it has the effect that on all nested features parallel execution instruction is ignored.
Is this kind of setup not supposed to work, or am I missing something here?

Reproducer

https://github.com/romanpierson/karate-playground

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes if a feature calls other features, those calls will not be run in parallel.

Comment: Thanks for confirming Thomas. Just out of curiosity, is there a specific reason this behavior is not supported? Or would you think of any way I could achieve this way of orchestration? The background to have such requirement would be to be able to run setups in parallel whereas each setup flow must be sequential. Also had a look at @setup but I see this will also not solve the issue.

Comment: @RomanPierson you can see if this answers some of your questions (use a `Scenario Outline`) https://stackoverflow.com/a/60387907/143475 - else this is a hard engineering problem and you are most welcome to look at the source and contribute improvements ;)