# can we read karate-config.js data in JAVA test Runner class?

Tags: javascript, java, karate

I have a requirement where in need to fetch karate-config.js data in my junit test runner to execute feature files based on conditional logic

karate-config.js file:-

```
    config.ACH = "Yes" 
    config.VISA = "No"
    config.MasterCard = "No"
    config.PAYPAL = "Yes"
```

I want to implement following logic in test runner java class:-

```
class default_TestRunner {

    @Karate.Test
    Karate testPostResult() {
        System.setProperty("karate.env", "qa");
if(config.ACH == "Yes" && config.PAYPAL == "Yes") // How to read these config data and exec specific feature files 
        return Karate.run("src/test/java/features/ACHE2E.feature","src/test/java/features/PAYPALE2E.feature").tags("~@ignore");
    
    
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is not supported and in my opinion the wrong approach. If you want to conditionally run tests depending on how tests are initiated, use tags: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#tags

There is a way in which you can use the `karate.env` to select (or un-select) tests. Maybe that's all you need.

Comment: I am bound to implement this approach as  in my case third party commits data in form of "Yes"/"No" in config.js to exec specific feature file.

Comment: I have implemented a approach:

Feature: 

  Background:
    * def execPayouts =
"""
function(x) {
    if (ACH == 'Yes') karate.call('classpath:src/test/java/features/ACHE2E.feature');
    if (PAYPAL == 'Yes') karate.call('classpath:src/test/java/features/PAYPALE2E.feature');

}
"""

Scenario: 

    * call execPayouts

But if first feature will have failures then second feature will not be executed.

Comment: @premgupta I will just say that there are plenty of other ways to do this in karate. look at examples like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60387907/143475 - but if you insist, all the best with what you are doing. maybe karate is not the right choice for you, just use Java or JS. you should not be mis-using `karate-config.js` like this.