# will karate run in parallel for browser automation feature files?

Tags: testing, browser, karate, browser-automation

As we know that the karate powerful feature is to run the test cases in parallel meaning running the feature files in parallel.
How this would work or apply for browser automation?
By the way, we have 2 config.
Head and Headless.

I assume that it is sequential when we use Head(Chrome) based on what I have noticed.
Please correct me if I am wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

```
class TestRunnerParallel {

@Test
void testParallel() {
    Results results = Runner.path("classpath:examples/users")
            //.outputCucumberJson(true)
            .parallel(4);
    assertEquals(0, results.getFailCount(), results.getErrorMessages());
}
}
```

To run using maven use following command:
mvn clean test -Dbrowser=chrome -Dtest=TestRunnerParallel

Official Doc:https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#parallel-execution

Comment: Hi @Faizil if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Comment: some additional info on UI parallel tests can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60387907/143475