# Unable to execute JavaScript functions after upgrading from 1.3.1 to 1.4.0+

Tags: karate

After upgrading to 1.4.0/1.4.1/1.5.0.RC1, i'm unable to use JavaScript functions after a call to another Feature File using Shared Scope - `* call read('classpath:CalledFeature.feature')`.

My JavaScript functions are defined in their own JavaScript file, which is called inside karate-config.js - `config = karate.call('classpath:utils/DataUtils.js', config);`

If I isolate the scope of the Feature File call then my JavaScript functions work fine, for example: `* def cf = call read('classpath:api/CalledFeature.feature')`.

This would be okay and I could work around by moving my shared scope calls to non-shared scope, but I have a UI Login Feature File that needs to stay as shared scope because it initialises a `driver` instance that my calling files need access to.

The error i'm seeing when trying to call a JavaScript function: `org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: TypeError: execute on {} failed due to: Message not supported.`

**Test.feature**

```
Feature: Test Upgrade from 1.3.1 to 1.4.0/1.4.1/1.5.1.RC1

    Background:

        # This works, but is not shared scope which is needed for UI tests
        #* def cf = call read('classpath:api/CalledFeature.feature')

        # This doesn't work but it is shared scope, which means the calling
        # feature file has access to any variables declared within the Called feature file
        # as well as the 'driver' instance used by the UI tests
        * call read('classpath:api/CalledFeature.feature')

    Scenario: Scenario 1

        * def myString = stringOfLength(10)
        * print myString
```

**CalledFeature.feature**

```
Feature: Test

    Scenario: Scenario 1
        * print "I am the called Feature"
```

**karate-config.js**

```
function fn() {
    config = karate.call('classpath:utils/DataUtils.js', config);
}
```

**DataUtils.js**

```
 function fn(config) {

    config.stringOfLength = function(length) {
        var stringToReturn = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                stringToReturn += "A";
            }
        return stringToReturn;
    }
    return config;
}
```

Comment: for a specific fix for the UI part try this: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#javascript-function-reuse - else I simply cannot help with the lack of info unless you follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - hopefully someone else here can give you better ideas

Comment: also the `driver` is deliberately designed not to be shared which may have become more stricter in 1.4.0 - you are welcome to contribute code to improve things - but for now, see if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60387907/143475

Comment: Thanks for the replies @PeterThomas. I'm not sure the solution in fetching the `driver` instance is the best for my situation as almost all 350 UI Scenarios make a call to a Login.feature. 

It's certainly a bit strange that called non-shared scope vs shared scope before calling a JS function means the JS functions no longer work. 

I'll look into following the process into raising an issue on GitHub. Thanks again.

Comment: if it is a bug we are more than happy to fix it. but we need a clear way to replicate it