# Launch test with Scenario Outline on several environments

Tags: karate

This very simple test simulates 2 users who wish to connect to their application to make a payment.
I want this test to run on the dev and recipe environments for each user.

To do this, I have 2 json data files:

- commons-data-recipe.json
- commons-data-dev.json

I've created a runner to launch my test or I can launch all my tests on the command line with maven.

The problem is that I'm encountering the following error:

> result is neither list nor function: [type: NULL, value: null]

This error occurs on the last line of the test : `| karate.setup().profile |`

Here's the test and the runner :

```
@UI
  Feature: do some stuff.

  @setup
  Scenario:
    * def configuration = call read('classpath:configuration.feature')
    * def profile = read('this:commons-data-' + configuration.env + '.json')

  Scenario Outline: Pay the product

    # connection
    Given driver loginUrl
    When input(commons.connection.login, '<login>')
    And input(commons.connection.password, '<password>')
    And click(commons.connection.connectionBtn)
    Then waitForUrl(homeUrl)

    # Add payment methods
    When input(quotationPage.paymentConditionSelect, '<paymentConditionSelect>')
    And waitFor(quotationPage.paymentConditionSelectOption).input(Key.ENTER)
    And input(quotationPage.paymentModeSelect, '<paymentModeSelect>')
    And waitFor(quotationPage.paymentModeSelectOption).input(Key.ENTER)
    Then match cleanGrossMargin contains '<cleanGrossMargin4>'
    
    # some other stuff...

    Examples:
      | karate.setup().profile | login | password  |
      | karate.setup().profile | toto  | password1 |
      | karate.setup().profile | titi  | password2 |
```

The runner:

```
@Karate.Test
Karate myTest() {
    return Karate.run("classpath:ui/blabla/umyTest.feature").relativeTo(getClass());
}
```

Thanks for help

Comment: pretty sure that `karate.setup().profile` is not something that will work for a "normal" `Examples:` table (where you have multiple rows). I suggest you create a simple example first, get that working (by printing out data to the console) and then only try advanced data-driven UI testing. also refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60387907/143475

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Finally, I did this stuff in the config.js:
function fn() {
  var config = karate.read('classpath:ui/blbabla/commons-data-' + env + '.json');
 
  return config;
}