# Karate Run Scenarios in Parallel using Feature File

Tags: testing, karate

How do I run tests in Parallel for multiple Scenarios in Karate? Is there an Annotation I can use, within the .feature file?

```
  | countryISO | 
  | 'USA'      |
  | 'GBR'      |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karate will run each row of a `Scenario Outline` `Examples` in parallel.

Are you using the Java API? Refer the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#parallel-execution

```
Results results = Runner.path("classpath:animals").parallel(5);
```

Or if you are using the command-line, there is a [CLI option](https://karatelabs.github.io/karate/karate-netty/#parallel-execution):

```
java -jar karate.jar -T 5 src/animals
```

Also refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60387907/143475